# Unknown Error on package installation

Tags: node.js, debian, npm

I am trying to install js-yaml package and getting such error, I am new in node and have no idea why it cause and how to fix?

Below is error trace

```
npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../esprima/bin/esparse.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this entire log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-46-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path ../esprima/bin/esparse.js
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: check your node version using `npm version` this issue has reported on node: 0.8.x

Comment: my current node version is v0.10.34

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue when installing to a VM hosted on windows (ntfs).
The issue is windows doesn't support symlinks.

Try adding `--no-bin-links` to the install command to not use symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

seem like there's some issues with **esprima** dependency

try `npm update esprima` or npm it self `npm -g update`